# Flex 4 select cell of datagrid on rollover

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am using a ItemRenderer with a spark Grid. I am needing to select my cells when the user roll over them.

If the mouse is down when they rollover then it should select the cell. If the mouse is not down then it should not select the cell.

Basically when they rollover the cell(s) it should be like they have clicked on them, trigger the click on the cell.

Comment: Do you mean like `selectionMode="singleCell"`?

Comment: I have it set to selectionMode="multipleCells". I need when user rollsover any of the cells they should be selected.

Comment: Select on rollover? That doesn't make much sense from a functional point of view. You'd never even be able to take any action on the selected cell, since once you rollout it will no longer be selected. Or will it?

Comment: Basically I need when they rollover the cells it should be like they clicked on them.

Comment: I edited my question. Maybe it makes more sense now?

Comment: So all you want is that the click event is dispatched? or is it more than that? Perhaps you should elaborate on your final intent (describe your problem in a more functional way).

Comment: Yes all I want is the click event dispatched for the cell(s) that are rolled over. I think that is all I need.

Comment: Can you not listen for the rollover event and then dispatch a click event on the currentTarget?